# How to get all collections using MongoEngine

Tags: python, mongodb, mongoengine

I can't seem to find any way to get a list of all collections using mongoengine in python. I need something similar to `list_collection_names()` in pymongo. Is this possible in mongoengine?

Comment: Use the same connection string to create a pymongo client and use that to list all collections.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import mongoengine

db = mongoengine.connection.get_db()

db.list_collection_names()
```